# Intellij idea - скрыть в редакторе левую вертикальную линию?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains, goland

[image]

Как скрыть **левую** вертикальную линию в редакторе кода Intellij Idea ? Та, что находится **между номеров строк и самим кодом**. Линию, что была справа, я успешно скрыл через Settigs - Editor - General - Appearance - Show hard wrap and visual guides, а вот для линии слева не могу найти такой настройки. Очень хотелось бы её скрыть, потому что режет глаза.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать поменять foreground color у **Tear line** в **Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | General, Editor**

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло